# Php change 5.0E-5 into 0.00000050

Tags: php

I am working on my site about bitcoins. And people can have balances there. I am btw working in php. In my `$user_data["balance"]` the value is `50`. And I want that to get converted by php into `0.00000050`. So I tried this:

```
$balance = $user_data["balance"] / 1000000;
```

But what I get from it, is this: `5.0E-5`. How to change it into `0.00000050`?

I would be really thankfull if somebody would help me!

Comment: Also note that you are a factor 100 off.

Answer (score 0):

Use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to get results with 8 decimals.

**Example-**

```
$balance = number_format($user_data["balance"] / 1000000,8,".","");
echo $balance; //output will 0.00005000
```

But if you want `0.00000050` then divide it by `100000000`

**Example**

```
$balance = number_format($user_data["balance"] / 100000000,8,".","");
echo $balance;  //output will 0.00000050
```